# If function differentiable in $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ then it's continuous on it

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $E$ is an open subset in $\mathbb{R}^n,$ $\mathbf{f}$ maps $E$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$. Prove that $\mathbf{f}$ is continuous at any point of E at which $\mathbf{f}$ is differentiable.

**Proof:** Let $\mathbf{x}\in E$ and $\mathbf{f}$ is differentianle at $\mathbf{x}$ then exists linear transformation $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $$\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h})-\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})=A\mathbf{h}+\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{h})$$ where $\dfrac{|\mathbf{r(h)}|}{|\mathbf{h}|}\to \mathbf{0}$ as $\mathbf{h}\to \mathbf{0}$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given then $\exists \delta_1>0$ such that for any $\mathbf{h}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $0<|\mathbf{h}|<\delta_1$ we have $|\mathbf{r(h)}|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}|\mathbf{h}|$. Taking $\delta=\min \{\delta_1,1,\frac{\epsilon}{2\lVert A\rVert }\}$(provided that $\lVert A\rVert\neq 0$) then for any $\mathbf{h}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $|\mathbf{h}|<\delta$ we have: $$|\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h})-\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})|\leqslant |A\mathbf{h}|+|\mathbf{r(h)}|\leqslant \lVert A\rVert|h|+|\mathbf{r(h)}|\leqslant\lVert A\rVert\delta+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}|\mathbf{h}|\leqslant \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon.$$
Hence $\mathbf{f}$ is continuous at $E$.
The case $\lVert A\rVert =0$ is more simple and analogous.

I am sorry if my topic repeated but I'm interested in correctness of my proof. Is it correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think's this is valid proof, but just a minor point: I think you could say $|r(h)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ instead of including $|h|$ there, since that's what it actually means to have $r(h)=o(|h|)$. Also, I'm pretty sure you are already aware of this but : $f(x+h)=f(x)+Ah+r(h) \to f(x)$ as $|h|\to 0$ so you get a continuity.

Comment: @user160738, how get that $|r(h)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$? Why didn't write $|h|$? Can you explain this please?

Comment: as you've written $|r(h)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2} |h|$ whenever $|h|\in (0,\delta_1)$, but certainly you could then say either $\delta_1<1$ or $\delta_1 \ge 1$. In formal case $|r(h)|<\varepsilon/2$ already, and latter case of course we can choose $\delta_1$ to be less then $1$, hence $|r(h)|<\varepsilon/2$. But I think this is pretty much what you did later when you chose $\delta$ so never mind that, I was just thinking you could do it a bit earlier.

Comment: @user160738, Thanks! +1